# Configure custom parameter converter serenity jbehave does not work

Tags: configuration, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I have updated my project's pom to use latest serenity and jbehave and since then using custom parameter converters are not working.

I have this (was enough with the old packages):

```java
configuration.useParameterConverters( 
    new ParameterConverters().addConverters( 
        new NumberStringConverter(),
        new ColorConverter(),
        new BooleanConverter() 
    ) 
);
```

The code is failing since it cannot find the right converter.

It seems, that the custom converters are applied for the beforeSteps and for the afterSteps, but not for the "standard" steps.

jbehave: 4.5
serenity-jbehave: 1.46.0

Any idea, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe serenity-behave 1.46.0 is built against jbehave 4.4, not 4.5. There is a PR to upgrade to jbehave 4.5 (https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-jbehave/pull/229) - maybe you could build the latest snapshot and see if that solves your problem (and if not, raise an issue against the PR).

Comment: thanks! reverting to jbehave 4.4 solved the problem.